# Constructing Markov chain

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, markov-chains

Let $(A_1,B_1)$ and $(A_2,B_2)$ be two random variables with the joint distributions $p_{A_1B_1}$ and $p_{A_2B_2}$, respectively. Moreover, we have
$$\mathbb{P}[(A_1,B_1)\neq (A_2,B_2)]=\alpha.$$
Then, there exists a random varible $(A',B')$ such that
\begin{align}
(A_1,B_1)=\begin{cases}
(A_2,B_2)&1-\alpha,\\
(A',B')&\alpha.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Let define the random variable $T$ as
\begin{align}
T=\begin{cases}
0&(A_1,B_1)=(A_2,B_2),\\
1&(A_1,B_1)\neq(A_2,B_2).
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Assume that we have two Markov chains $A_2-D_2-B_2$ and $A'-D'-B'$. Then, does the following Markov chain hold?
\begin{align}
A_1-(D_1,T)-B_1,
\end{align}
in which $D_1$ is
\begin{align}
D_1=\begin{cases}
(D_2,0)&(A_1,B_1)=(A_2,B_2),\\
(D',1)&(A_1,B_1)\neq(A_2,B_2).
\end{cases}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

No, in general you don't have the Markov property for $A_1 \to (D_1, T) \to B_1$.

For example, suppose $(A_2, B_2)$ is uniform on $\{0,1\}^2$, and $(A',B')$ is uniform on $\{0,1\}\times\{2,3\}$.

Note that $A_2$ and $B_2$ are independent, and so are $A'$ and $B'$. So if we let $D_2$ and $D'$ be trivial (i.e. taking a single value), then $A'\to D'\to B'$ and $A_2\to D_2\to B_2$ both have the Markov property.

Now define
$$
(A_1, B_1)=\begin{cases} 
(A_2, B_2)&\text{if } A_2=B_2\\
(A', B')&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$

This satisfies your conditions with $\alpha=1/2$. We have $T=0$ iff $A_2= B_2$.

However, it's not the case that $A_1 \to T \to B_1$ has the Markov property. $A_1$ and $B_1$ are not conditionally independent given $T$; given $T=0$, the conditional distribution of $(A_1, B_1)$ is uniform on $\{(0,0), (1,1)\}$.

[By the way, you have to be careful writing things like the second displayed equation in your question. What does it mean to say something like
\begin{align}
(A_1,B_1)=\begin{cases}
(A_2,B_2)& \text{with probability }1-\alpha,\\
(A',B')& \text{with probability }\alpha.
\end{cases}\,\, ?
\end{align}
For example, this is problematic if there is positive probability that $(A_2, B_2)=(A', B')$. Then on the face of it, some outcomes will contribute *both* to the probability $1-\alpha$ *and* to the probability $\alpha$.]

Comment: Thsnk you so much. Is there any way to construct a Markov chain for $A_1-?-B_1$ based on $D_2$ and $D'$?

Comment: @Math_Y In that example I just used, $D_2$ and $D'$ are trivial. So I'm not sure what kind of "construction" based on $D_2$ and $D'$ you could mean?